# Why is there no change in memory usage when I clear a table in DolphinDB?

Tags: database, memory-management, in-memory-database, dolphindb

I create an in-memory table in DolphinDB with the following script:

```
date=rand(2012.06.01..2012.06.30,100000)
time=rand(13:30:10.008..14:30:10.008,100000)
id=rand(symbol(string(100..200)),100000)
vnet_lisn_bps_avg_t=rand(100.0,100000)
t=table(date,time,id,vnet_lisn_bps_avg_t)
```

I check the memory usage with the function `getSessionMemoryStat`. The result is as follows:

[image]

Then I clear the table with the function `clear!` and check the memory usage again. There is no change in the result.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The function `clear!` deletes all rows of an in-memory table, but it doesn't release allocated memory of the table. To release the table completely, undefine variable `t` or set it to null

```
//release the variable t by undef function
undef(`t, VAR)

//release the table by releasing the reference count
t = NULL
```